# Pass parameters into Solidity Constructor from Truffle CONSOLE

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-test, truffle-deployment, truffle-compile

How do we pass in constructor parameters to a contract that we want to test? I understand that the initial contract deployment occurs in the `migrations` file, but if, for testing/debugging purposes, we want to deploy and instantiate the contract in the Truffle Console, how do we do so? How about in our testing files?

Per instance, say our `ExampleContract.sol` file is:

`contract ExampleContract { function ExampleContract(uint256 my_param){} })`

And our `2_deploy_contracts.js` file has this line at the top, but doesn't deploy the contract :

`var ExampleContract = artifacts.require("./ExampleContract.sol");`

We open a Truffle Ganache console & then migrate our stuff in:

`truffle console --network ganache`

`migrate --compile-all`

Now, we have the contract's information (including its address) stored in `ExampleContract`, but how can we then instantiate it with parameters we wish to pass into its constructor? What is the equivalent of the `deployer.deploy` object in `migrations` that we may pass parameters into?

Answer (score 1):

It's little wordy on the command line.

You're looking for `new`.

Try:

```
var c;
ExampleContract.new(arg1, arg2)
.then(function(instance) {
  c = instance;
});
```

That will deploy a new one with args passed to the constructor.

It did not use the deployer, so won't update the migrations registry.

Hope it helps.